# How to make an android application to intract with internet

Tags: android, html, button, mobile, android-edittext

I made some simle android applications like addind and multiplying two number with two edit text and one button and some other simple applications. But i dont know how to make an application to intract with internet, for eg. creating a layout to display the content of a web page. I am a bigginer to android application making I know my question is childish but if i get an idea for how it works it will be a great thing to me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: trivial....just search webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying a webpage in an application, you can use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). You could also scrap a webpage using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) (a Java library) if you wanted to only display certain parts of a webpage. For example, with Jsoup you could scrap a certain part of a website, and then display that in a `TextView`.

An example of a `WebView`:

In your XML layout file for the activity:

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Then in your activity Java file, you would have:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

You would also need to add this to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: thanks a lot hichris, i have to experiment with it and develop more i expect more coparation from you

Comment: it works great thanks for it but mu intention is to show the current weather of a particular place as a text in between a string on layout i tried for it a lot and google it some says about api of yahoo weather i don't know how to work with the api once i get the method i hop i can do the rest so please help me, i know you know the methord